# How to remove the tqdm progress bar but keep the iteration info

Tags: python, tqdm

To hide the `tqdm` progress bar after running a computation I pass `leave=False`, as in the following example code:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

text = ""
for char in tqdm(["a", "b", "c", "d"], desc="Loop", leave=True):
    sleep(0.25)
    text = text + char
```

However, I would like to keep the iteration statistics when the loop is done (hiding the bar), for example:

```
Loop: 4 [00:01,  3.99it/s]
```

for total number of iterations, total time taken and iterations per second. Is there a way to do this?

I tried doing

```py
class tqdm_f(tqdm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.done_fmt = kwargs.pop("done_fmt",
                                   "{desc}: {total_fmt} [{elapsed}, {rate_fmt}{postfix}]")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_to(self, b=1, bsize=1, tsize=None):
        if b * bsize == self.total:
            self.bar_format = self.done_fmt
        self.update(b * bsize - self.n)  # will also set self.n = b * bsize
```

and using my `tqdm_f` instead but that did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ncols` of tqdm to zero in the last iteration:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

text = ""
progress_bar = tqdm(["a", "b", "c", "d"], desc="Loop")
for char in progress_bar:
    sleep(0.25)
    text = text + char
    if char == "d":
        progress_bar.ncols=0
```

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#documentation), setting `ncols` to zero will cause the bar to disappear. To do so only in the last iteration will keep the bar in all previous iterations. There's no need to use the `leave` argument.

---

**Alternative:** If you want to remove the bar altogether, you can set `ncols` to zero right from the start:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

text = ""
for char in tqdm(["a", "b", "c", "d"], desc="Loop", ncols=0):
    sleep(0.25)
    text = text + char
```